# I cannot seem to understand my current errors in this C# code for counting characters from an input field

Tags: c#

This is my code, any help / recommendations would be helpful! Thanks in advance!

I'm creating a form that counts characters from an input field. I think I have most of it written correctly, but I get a few errors:

[This is the list of errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPqaQ.png)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Wk5Ch12Exer9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String inputText = null;

        // How do I decide on below number?
        int[] charFrequency = new int[52];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputText = rtbInputArea.Text;
        }

        private void processLine(String strng)
        {
            if (strng.Equals(null))
                return;

            char[] current = strng.ToCharArray();

            for (int idx = 0; idx < current.Length; idx++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (current[idx]>= 65 &&
                        current[idx] <= 90)
                    {
                        charFrequency[current[idx] - 65] += 1;
                    }
                    else if (current[idx] >= 97 &&
                             current[idx] <= 122)
                    {
                        charFrequency[current[idx] - 97 + 26] += 1;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { 
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
            String[] inp = inputText.Split('\n');

            for (int idx = 0; idx < inp.Length; idx++)
            {
                processLine(inp[idx]);
            }

            for (int ins = 0; ins < 26; ins++)
            {
                if (charFrequency[ins] != 0)
                {
                    output.Append("Frequency of " +
                        (char)(ins + 65) + " is: " +
                        charFrequency[ins] + "\n");
                }
            }

            for (int ins = 26; ins < charFrequency.Length; ins++)
            {
                if (charFrequency[ins] != 0)
                {
                    outputAppend("Frequency of " +
                        (char)(ins + 97 - 26) +
                        " is: " +
                        charFrequency[ins] + "\n");
                }
            }

            rtbOutputArea.Text = output.ToString();
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtbInputArea.Text = "";
            rtbOutputArea_TextChanged.Text = "";
            charFrequency = new int[52];
        }
    }
}
```

I am truly so incredibly lost at what I am to do. I keep googling and just end up getting even more confused.

Comment: Start with a `Dictionary<char,int>` and you can avoid all the math.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting idea! Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the answer given which shortcuts your `char` frequencies, issues with your code: 1. `strng == null` is the normal way of doing that 2. No need for `ToCharArray`, you can loop a string anyway 3. Don't swallow exceptions with empty catch blocks 4. `.Split(new char[]{'\n','\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )` is probably better 5. I see no need for splitting anyway, you could just process the whole original string 6. `rtbOutputArea_TextChanged.Text = "";` is obviously wrong 7. Judging by your other errors, you appear to have lost your `.Designer.cs` code-behind

Answer (score 0):

Start with a dictionary:

```
var dict = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            .ToDictionary(k=>k,k=>0);
```

Check if the character in your string is in the dictionary, and if so increment:

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(c))
{
  dict[c]+=1;
}
```

Output:

```
var s = dict
  .Where(k=>k.Value>0)
  .Select(k=>$"Frequency of {k.Key} is {k.Value}")
var output = string.Join("\n", s);
```

Or using Linq GroupBy:

```
var strng = "This is just a test.";

var arr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  .ToCharArray();
var g = strng
  .Where(arr.Contains)
  .GroupBy(s=>s)
  .OrderBy(s=>s.Key)
  .Select(s=>$"Frequency of {s.Key} is {s.Count()}");

var output = string.Join("\n", g);
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks for elaborating from the other comment! This helps!

Comment: You could of course, just use a .GroupBy as well, which would make it trivial.